# How to Fetch Field Value from Column Name

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable

Whilst in the process of moving from vb.net to c#, I have run into this problem with the use of a `datatable`.  So, here you see I want to fetch the value of a field from row #1 by referencing the name of the column header:

In vb.net, I was able to do this:

```
Dim mydatatable as As New System.Data.DataTable
Dim myvar as string
myvar = mydatatable.Rows(1).Item("mycategory")
```

But there is no `.item()` in C#.  There is, however, `DataArray[]`, but it only accepts integers.

```
something.InnerText = thisdata.Rows[1].ItemArray[1].ToString();
```

Am I right to believe that I must loop through all the *column headers* to match the column's name and then fetch it's index?  Or is there a way to work like I have in vb.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rows[1]` returns second row, which is of [`DataRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type. Row also has several indexers, which accepts [column name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [DataColumn object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5akhx035%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [column index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwfe1t7z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) etc:

```
something.InnerText = thisdata.Rows[1]["mycategory"].ToString();
```

Basically line above is equivalent to following, where row is explicitly stored in local variable:

```
DataRow row = thisdata.Rows[1];
something.InnerText = row["mycategory"].ToString();
```

But here it's completely clear what happens.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't realize that `Rows` was a multidimensional array.  I have to wait 12 more minutes to mark the answer...

Comment: @BGM not exactly - Rows is a sinlge-dimiensional collection, which contains DataRows. But rows have indexers. That is not same as multidimensional array, which would look like `rowsArray[rowIndex, columnIndex]`

Comment: Ah. I appreciate the lesson. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you have named columns, you can reference those columns inside a bracket.

```
myvar = mydatatable.Rows[1]["mycategory"]
```

You can also use indexes.

```
myvar = mydatatable.Rows[1][1]
```